# 'FavoriteManager' object has no attribute 'get_query_set'

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-favorites from https://bitbucket.org/last_partizan/django-favorites/overview, and I set everything right and when I run the code it gave me `'FavoriteManager'` object has no attribute `'get_query_set'`. The error was occuring from the django-favorites `models.py` from this line

```
qs = self.get_query_set().filter(content_type=content_type, object_id=obj.pk)
```

So I thought, I need to specify object. So I'm trying to use `fav button` for all my `Post`, so I need to change `obj` to Post. But even after changing I get same error. What is going on with this?

This is `models.py` inside favorite app, where error is occurring

```
def favorites_for_object(self, obj, user=None):
       """ Returns Favorites for a specific object """
       content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(obj))
       qs = self.get_query_set().filter(content_type=content_type, 
                                         object_id=obj.pk)
       if user:
           qs = qs.filter(user=user)

       return qs
```

This is where I'm calling fav_item

```
<div class="actions">{% fav_item post user %}</div>
```

Lets say I want to put fav_item on my category model

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.name,instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name
```

Then doesn't it make sense to import 
`main.models` import Category
and switch obj to Category. Unfortunately there's not much documentation here: https://bitbucket.org/last_partizan/django-favorites/overview

Comment: everytime I get new edit, I'm like ohh I finally got some notifiaction maybe this will be fixed and I see edit then I'm like oh.....:)

Comment: why is this keep getting edited which doesn't really help but not being answered!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is related to Django version. The method `get_query_set` has been removed from Django 1.8.x . Before that, this method was used by `RenameManagerMethods`. Check this github source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/models/manager.py#L56

Also `django-favorites` was last updated in 2013, as I can see from the source. You should consider downgrading your Django version.

Comment: thank you, I was googling every wehre. I still want to use this and don't want to downgrade, is there a way?

Comment: Well, you need to re-write the `django-favorites` for that, because it is not compatible with latest Django versions.

Comment: by the way, I shouldn't change obj to the model I want to use fav_tag for?

Comment: don't I just need to replace get_query_set with the some command that has replaced get_query_set?

Comment: you can replace `get_query_set` with `get_queryset` in model. That should solve this issue.

Comment: ok, and about the question I asked, my approach to change obj to category is wrong because that way I'm changing the app?

Comment: I am bit unclear about your question, but I think you shouldn't change code in  `models.py` in `favorites` library other than the previous suggestion I made. You can follow the example mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: thank you I followed it there and now I got a new error, I created a new forum for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760346/i-have-no-idea-what-my-error-means-noreversematch-at-sssss-reverse-for-wit