# I have no idea what my error means: NoReverseMatch at /sssss/ Reverse for '' with arguments '(9, 19)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-urls

I'm using django-favorites for follow/unfollow strategy. https://bitbucket.org/last_partizan/django-favorites/overview
Problem is this might be wrote for django lower than 1.7 maybe and I'm using django 1.8. 
I fixed most of errors but now I get NoReverseMatch at /sssss/

> Reverse for '' with arguments '(9, 19)' and keyword arguments '{}' not
>   found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

I have no idea what this is or how to fix this. 
It says it's coming from fav_item.html,which is part of app. 
from this line `{% url ajax_fav ctype.id item.id %}`

Here is the rest of the code

```
<a href="#" class="favIt" id="FavIt_{{ item.id }}" data-action-url="{% url ajax_fav ctype.id item.id %}">{{ message }}</a> 
<span class="favsCounter" id="FavCounter_{{ item.id }}">{{ counter }}</span>
```

I'm trying to use it on my category model

```
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.name,instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name
```

Is this ajax problem?really what does the error mean...

Really hope this gets fixed

Edit:

```
  from django.conf.urls import *

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^fav/(?P<ctype_id>\d+)/(?P<obj_id>\d+)/$', 'favorites

.views.ajax_fav', name="ajax_fav"),        
)
```

views.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
import json as simplejson
from favorites import settings as fav_settings
from favorites.models import Favorite
from favorites.utils import build_message

def ajax_login_required(view_func):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        json = simplejson.dumps({'not_authenticated': True})
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json', status=401)
    wrap.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__
    wrap.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
    return wrap

@ajax_login_required
def ajax_fav(request, ctype_id, obj_id):
    """

    """
    ctype = get_object_or_404(ContentType, pk=ctype_id)
    item = ctype.get_object_for_this_type(pk=obj_id)    
    if Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, content_type=ctype, object_id=obj_id):
        fav = Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, content_type=ctype, object_id=obj_id)
        fav.delete()
        count = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_object(item).count()
        data_dict = {'id': 0, 'message': fav_settings.FAV_ADD, 'counter': build_message(count), }
    else:        
        fav = Favorite.objects.create_favorite(item, request.user)
        count = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_object(item).count()
        data_dict = {'id': fav.id, 'message': fav_settings.FAV_REMOVE, 'counter': build_message(count), }
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Comment: before this: I had this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758162/favoritemanager-object-has-no-attribute-get-query-set/34759580?noredirect=1#comment57265830_34759580

Comment: @Baterson hey man, I figured out thumbnail image problem, remember me/

Comment: @Sayse sure, it's from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^fav/(?P<ctype_id>\d+)/(?P<obj_id>\d+)/$', 'favorites.views.ajax_fav', name="ajax_fav"),        
)

Comment: Please use the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34760346/edit) to add new information, You may need to include the view also

Comment: @Sayse, btw I didn't write this, it's still part of the app django-favorites

Comment: @Sayse, hello I edited with url and view

Comment: @Sayse, any suggestion??

Comment: Its hard to see what the issue is without knowing what is included in the urls.py files that construct the path, the view looks ok so it may be worth updating your question with just the relevant urls.py, your model isn't the problem

Comment: Here's my base urls.py: https://github.com/lip365/ebagu0.2/blob/master/rclone/rclone/urls.py and this is where my other urls.py https://github.com/lip365/ebagu0.2/blob/master/rclone/main/urls.py

Comment: @Sayse I heard many good things about this app,,,so I tried to use follow/unfollow for this...but gives me some problems I'm thinking it's the last barrier

Comment: @Sayse should i just give up on this app......?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this app, you will need to copy over that template into your own app and change that line to use quotes around the view name:

```
{% url "ajax_fav" ctype.id item.id %}
```

Comment: oh I was about to give up,  copy that fav html into my html?

Comment: wow thank you, I'm not sure why but putting quote there works. what do you mean by I need to copy template over to my app? do you mean I need to put <a href="#" class="favIt" id="FavIt_{{ item.id }}" data-action-url={% url "ajax_fav" ctype.id item.id %}>{{ message }}</a> 
<span class="favsCounter" id="FavCounter_{{ item.id }}">{{ counter }}</span>
to my html file where "likes" is being used?

Comment: at least I can eat now,,,putting this aside